# How does character progression work in Dungeon Defenders?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

When leveling up in Dungeon Defenders, you're given skill points that you can put in various areas of character development, including personal stats, personal skills, and tower stats.

I have a few questions regarding this system.

- Can you get these points back and redistribute them elsewhere?
- Is there a maximum amount that each option can be progressed?
- If there is a max level per skill, does that mean that at the level cap (100), you have every skill maxed? Or is there still the potential for different builds at the level cap (100)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [wiki](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Tavernkeep), yes, you *can* respec your heroes.

Based on this [leveling guide](http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Stat_Distribution_Guide), you can get 5 skills to 50, and get a 6th to 49 points for a total of 299 points. Thus, you will never be able to max out all your skills.

The maximum per skill is 70.

Comment: I would like to point out that it has become apparent that the maximum skill level for some abilities is not 50.  My Huntress, for instance, has 70 Hero Damage and 70 Trap Damage.

Comment: @Tux yes, the max skill level is 70, I the second sentence was just a way for me to figure out that the maximum number of skills is 299, now that I have a char at 70, I guess I can remove that part and just state it.

Answer (score 6):

The **maximum** number of points you can put into a skill is actually 120 (it used to be 100, and lower before that).

The total number of points a character has (was) 299 at level 70, so you couldn't max every  skill.

Comment: actually my hero has one skill point that has 127 points in it so the cap can't be 120

Comment: Are you sure that your gear isn't give you bonuses that put you over 120? Because that's the intended design. If you mouse over the skill it will tell you how much is coming from skills and how much from equipment.